# Need assistance to figure out a title (amoeba like parasite)

Tags: story-identification, books

There was a sci-fi or fantasy novel.  There was a male primary character.  He had either enhanced brain or was really smart.  The setting was sort of middle ages after a war i believe.  Either way there were ruins, and normal people lived in small settlements.

The main character goes to one of the ruins.  It is populated by humans who have been taken over by amoeba like parasites.  The parasites latch onto their hosts head, and take over their bodies.  The hero in turn dominates the amoeba parasite, and in so doing increases his vision, mental memory, and after a fashion is able to disuse his face.

I seem to remember bits about a guy that had damage and the hero uses a juvenile amoeba to fix him.  It might be mixing stories, but there might be force fields that separate different territories.  Each area has different levels of tech, ect...  Possibly putting these things on your head, the fields do not affect you.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: This seems familiar… can you provide an approximate date for either publication or when you read it?

Comment: I think it was one of the more well known sci-fi authors.  Not sure which.  I think, it was an older book.  I would say pre-1990's. It might be part of a series.